# can i start app using blazor server then load webassembly?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

can I load, render the main page first using blazor server, then switch to a subpage and run it using webassembly?
I know I can create webassembly + asp.net but then the main page is displayed using webassembly (seo unfriendly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... but then the main page is displayed (seo unfriendly)

What you are looking for is called "server prerendering".

It requires hosting on asp.net (using the Webassembly hosted model).

See [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly) and also search the term for more walk-throughs and videos.

[Here](https://andrewlock.net/enabling-prerendering-for-blazor-webassembly-apps/) is a useful blog that links to a few more.